# Is it possible to dynamically create an JPA repository object

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm having a case where I need to modify all the entities (Generic Type) in a single service class. Instead of auto wiring all the available repository interfaces, is there any method to initialize the given JPA entity's repository alone?

Pls anyone let me know?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of modification are you talking about? Set a persistent attribute? If so, just inject a `EntityManager` and execute a update DML statement. Also see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#Update_Queries

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple repositories to manipulate in a service, create a wrapper class for all of them then expose appropriate methods. More like wrapping using the adapter pattern. That way you only have 1 dependency to inject in your main service class. I’m not sure if this helps, maybe let me know